# Block client IP address for a KTor server?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have a KTor server that provides REST type services to my KTor clients.
I just want to protect my server from brute force attack, as well as some just trying to bring down my server by searching every page with infite requests.
Logically, I need to maintain a list of all incoming IP addresses and then add someone in the blocked IP list when an IP address makes 100 requests in 1 minute.

1. How do you get the IP address of the client in the Ktor server? (malicious clients could be coming from Chrome, postman, curl, etc. and not necessarily from my Ktor clients, so need IP address to identify a client)
2. Where do I put the put the code to ckeck IP addresses so that the good clients are least affected?

Comment: You might want to consider putting your server behind a reverse proxy instead of trying to roll your own DoS/DDoS protections. e.g. nginx: https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-ddos-attacks-with-nginx-and-nginx-plus/

Comment: While nginx is a possible solution, I am trying to implement a solution that does not involve using a reverse proxy.

Comment: The problem with coupling this type of defense into your server is if a "brute force" attack happens, you're still devoting application resources to trying to sort out which requests are legitimate and which are not. At some point service is degraded even if all you're doing is throwing illegitimate requests out.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, try to avoid home-grown cyber security measures if you can. Battle-tested tools might require some effort upfront to learn, but will save you a lot of time (and headache when they are really put to the test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of hours I finally figured out the right way:

```
//tried this on a webhook, where call = ApplicationCall inside the PipelineContext block

post("/page")
{
    val clientIP = call.request.origin.remoteAddress.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can get the IP address from the `RequestConnectionPoint` object:

```
embeddedServer(Netty, host = "localhost", port = 9090) {
    routing {
        get("/") {
            val ip = call.request.local.remoteAddress
            call.respondText { ip }
        }
    }
}.start(wait = true)
```

2. You can create a plugin and put the logic for checking IP addresses in the  handler of the `onCall` method, which is executed on each HTTP call:

```
val plugin = createApplicationPlugin("plugin") {
    onCall {
        // Check IP addresses here
    }
}

suspend fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, host = "localhost", port = 9090) {
        install(plugin)
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

Comment: localhost gives the IP address of the hardware which is hosting the application. remoteAddress is what you need to use for getting the client IP address.